# Chainlink Docker Failing to Create /chainlink/ directory

Tags: nodes, chainlink, ubuntu, docker

I am running into this issue `"Error creating root directory \"/chainlink\": chmod /chainlink: operation not permitted"` when running the Chainlink node docker.

```
latestimage=$(curl -s -S "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/smartcontract/chainlink/tags/" | jq -r '."results"[]["name"]' | head -n 1)

cd /home/ec2-user/.chainlink

sudo docker run -d \
--log-driver=awslogs \
--log-opt awslogs-group=ChainlinkLogs \
--restart unless-stopped \
-u 1000:1000 \
--name chainlink \
-p 6688:6688 \
-v /home/ec2-user/.chainlink:/chainlink \
--env-file=/home/ec2-user/.chainlink/.env  smartcontract/chainlink:$latestimage local n \
-p /chainlink/.password \
-a /chainlink/.api
```

I ran `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` and `sudo chmod -R 777 /home/ec2-user/.chainlink` and I keep getting the same error.

My `.env`, `.api`, and `.password` live in `/home/ec2-user/.chainlink`, and the `ROOT` variable in `.env` is set to `ROOT=/chainlink`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your docker run command you have the option `-u 1000:1000` which comes with certain privelages to the `.chainlink` directory.

To give the right permissions to the `.chainlink` directory, please try:

```
sudo chown 1000:1000 /home/ec2-user/.chainlink
```